# Double Spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This code should show an `alert` box if there are no double spaces but it's not doing that.

```
var str = prompt("Enter Some Text");
var numChars = str.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
    if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ") {
        alert("No double spaces!");
        break;
    }
}
```

alert will pop out if no double spaces

Comment: `=== " "` <-- this is comparing an array to a single whitespace. You rather want: `str.slice(i, i + 2).every(s => s === ' ')` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this a little simpler with an `indexOf` check:

```js
var str = prompt("Enter Some Text");
if (str.indexOf("  ") === -1) {
  alert("No double spaces!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple regular expression can do it :

```js
const str = prompt("Enter Some Text");
!/\s\s/.test(str) && alert('No double spaces found !');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that with the `for` approach, you should invert the logic and check whether the double whitespace occurs:

```js
var str = prompt("Enter Some Text");
var numChars = str.length;

var doubleWhitespace = false;
for (var i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
  // get the current and next character.
  var [curr, next] = [str[i], str[i + 1]];
  // if both exists and current is the same as next and both the characters are spaces
  if (curr && next && curr === next && curr === ' ') {
    // double white space.
    doubleWhitespace = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (doubleWhitespace) alert('There is a double space!');
else alert('NO double space');
```

However, there is a slightly easier solution by just using `indexOf`:

```js
var str = prompt("Enter Some Text");
if (str.indexOf('  ') > -1) alert("There are double spaces!");
else alert("There are no double spaces!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need change this line

```
if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === " ") {
```

with

```
if (str.slice(i, i + 2) === "  ") {
```